# python math.log(1/2) domain error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a weird problem with python's math library's log function

```
>> math.log(1/2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error

>> math.log(0.5)
-0.6931471805599453
```

Why is this happening? 
My python version is 2.7.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/2 == 0 in python 2 and log(0) is -Inf, try:

```
math.log(1./2)
```

Comment: I'm using it in a function, calling something like math.log(num/num2)

Comment: try: math.log(float(num)/num2)

Comment: @JasonWoo: Or use `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file to make Python always do floating point division with `x / y` within that file.  Use `x // y` if you need integer (rounded/floored) division.